# Leaflet. Why I should create controls with Leaflet way?

Tags: leaflet

I'm new to Leafletjs, I've just started to creating my first project with this template and I have mixed feelings about Leaflet controls. It seems really time consumig to create complex control window by extending L.control object.

I'm thinking about creating control window with just jquery. Are there any advices, why I should not do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use [Leaflet's excellent controls for preventing clicks/other events](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domevent-stoppropagation) from "falling" thru to the map/vectors/anything possibly below it and triggering unwanted events?

So that other plugins that interact with `L.Control` in some way can interoperate together? Overall, it makes the sharing & improvement of plugins easier if it is done the "Leaflet" way. `L.Control` is really not that complicated in terms of molding to fit your own purposes.